# Where is Downloads folder in WSL Ubuntu linux for Windows?

Tags: download, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Hello I am trying to find Downloads folder of ubuntu can somebody loot at the this image and help me with locating the folder.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From the Picture you provided, Downloads should be in your Home folder. That is where it is located on my Ubuntu machine.

It is just a folder, so if for whatever reason, there is not one, just make a folder called Downloads in Home.

Comment: Did you find or make your Downloads folder?